# Clasp push unable to find .clasp.json file

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, package.json, clasp

I am using Clasp to clone code from a Google Apps Script project to a project on my local machine. The cloning works fine, and the code from the GAS project is now present in my VS Code folder. However, when I make a change and try to push it to the original GAS project, I get the following error:

> No valid /Users/iancampbell/Desktop/GAS/test_gas/.clasp.json project file. You may
> need to `create` or `clone` a project first.

I am confused by this error, because my project very clearly has a .clasp.json file, and I have just cloned a project. The .clasp.json file also has the same script ID I used to clone.

[image]

I also tried running the command from the apps-script folder as well, and that made no difference.

Here is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "test_gas",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "delete": "del-cli --force ./apps-script",
    "folder:": "mkdir apps-script",
    "glogin": "clasp login",
    "glogout": "clasp logout",
    "gcreate": "clasp create --title 'React Test Project' --rootDir './apps-script' ",
    "gclone": "clasp clone 1YNAbrnPfOdXFKKuEO90JxnWZ0x9njHa3zlb3s3O8_pdBCc6OpoWuD3Gc --rootDir ./apps-script",
    "gpull": "clasp pull",
    "gpush": "clasp push ",
    "gstart": "clasp push --watch",
    "start": "parcel src/index.html --dist-dir ./apps-script",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html --dist-dir ./apps-script",
    "runall": "npm-run-all delete folder gclone"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@google/clasp": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/google-apps-script": "^1.0.62",
    "multi-clasp2": "^3.0.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "del-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  }
}
```

When I used clasp create, this issue does not happen. But when I clone an existing GAS project and then try to update it, this error continues to appear. Is there a different npm command I should run?

Comment: Have you tried `cd` into `./apps-script` before **push** or **move** `.clasp.json` to the parent `/Users/iancampbell/Desktop/GAS/test_gas/`?

Comment: I tried to cd into the file, and that didn't work, but interestingly enough, moving the .clasp.json file to the root directory did the trick and the push worked. Thanks!